# Convert HTML into PDF file

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, pdf

I have string contains HTML type of data and I am simply trying to convert them into PDF using ASP.Net. I've looked around in the support pages and Googled it a lot! There seems to be no simple snippet of code to this is common task with a nice output. To be more specific, if is it possible to convert whole html page (With css) into a PDF file like wise what any browser does for us.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: If you use windows and Microsoft office, you could use COM Interop.Word and open html file using WordApplication and close as Pdf format. If it can work for you let me know, I can provide a code that do this.

Comment: Sure, it should be .net.

Comment: I am working on ASP.Net with javascript and jQuery. I am not using windows and MS Office integration. It would be highly appreciable for me if you would suggest free third party software that will fulfill my purpose.

Comment: A client-only solution would be the Adobe Acrobat extension for google chrome:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adobe-acrobat/efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj

Comment: Thanks again. I can't use any type of extension as I have to achieve via Coding... :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)

[Example code](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/)

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't use my hand over pdf.js. Will it convert whole my page layout into appropriate PDF file.